# How to mock external class in another initialized in another class?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have following files and classes

```
//A.ts 

export abstract class A{
    
    protected abstract method1(arg){
        
    }
}

// Session.ts
export class Session{
    constructor(socket: WebSocket){
         this._socket = socket;
         this._socket.on('close', () => {do something} );
         this._socket.on('error', () => {do something} );
         this._socket.on('message', () => {do something} );
    }
    setSomeSocket(someSocket: WebSocket){
         this._anotherSocket = someSocket;
         this._anotherSocket.on('close', () => {do something} );
         this._anotherSocket.on('error', () => {do something} );
    };
}


// B.ts
    export class B extends A{
       
        protected async method1(arg){
            try{
                let tempSession = new Session();
                tempSession.setSomeSocket(socket);
                // do something with temp
            }
            catch(exception){
                
            }
        }
    }


// B.spec.ts
describe("B test", () => {
    it("some test", () => {
        const varB = new B();
        
        await varB["method1"](arg);
        expect(spied).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

I want to mock the class Session so that it doesn't create any problem in socket.on() methods. I am sending mocked websockets.
The class is external and I want the mock implementation inside test file such that when running the test, the mocked class gets called inside B.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can mock directly with the jest:

```js
jest.mock('./Session');

beforeEach(() => {
    Session.mockClear();
})
```

Check out the manual mocking and auto mocking from Jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks).

Comment: Could you please explain little bit more how can I mock the class Session and its methods?

Comment: When the test file is running your code file, it checks your imports. So you are importing the './Session' file. 

```js
const mockSetSomeSocket = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./Session', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {setSomeSocket: mockSetSomeSocket};
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to mock if I have more than one method in the Session class

Comment: Keep adding in to the return object as in the example, if you check the documentation on the answer, you can find various examples.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in another comment you can mock Session with [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks)

```js
const mockSetSameSocks = jest.fn(); // note name starts with mock, important
jest.mock('./Session', () => {
  return {
    Session: jest.fn(() => ({
      setSameSocks: mockSetSameSocks,
    }))
  }
});

// B.spec.ts
describe("B test", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockSetSameSocks.mockClear();
  })

  it("some test", () => {
    const varB = new B();
        
    await varB["method1"](arg);
    expect(mockSetSameSocks).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
})
```

Comment: How to mock the constructor of Sesssion class? Should I create another mocked method named mockConstructor and assign that to constructor the same way?